# How to reset the iframe

Tags: javascript, .net, iframe

```
tbar: function (callback) {
    var items = [];
    items.push(lazyMethod_TopBarMenuBuilder("Create", false, "add16", "create1", function () { lazyMethod_OpenWindow('Vessel Detail', 'panelWindowId', 600, 1000, 'vos001_view.aspx') ; }));
    items.push(lazyMethod_TopBarMenuBuilder("Save", false, "add16", "save", fn_save));
    items.push(lazyMethod_TopBarMenuBuilder("Remove", false, "add16", "remove", remove));
    items.push(lazyMethod_TopBarMenuBuilder("Reset", false, "add16", "reset", resetform));
    items.push(lazyMethod_TopBarMenuBuilder("Export", false, "add16", "export", ""));
    callback(items);
},z
```

When click on the top bar reset i need the whole form to reset but after testing for hours still don't have the solution.

This is the function i use to reset the form but it is not working .

**function resetform() {
    document.getElementById("formdetail").reset();**

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var iframeID = $('iframe').attr('id');
  alert(iframeID);
$('#' + iframeID).attr('src', function (i, val) { return val; });
```

this function works it get the iframe id and reset.

Answer (score 0):

With vanilla Javascript:

```
document.querySelector('iframe').setAttribute('src','')
```